# Google Analytics: what % of unique users visited a page (1 or more times)?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a chat feature on my site, which some of my users LOVE, and some don't use at all. I'd like to know how many of my users visited the chat page (% of total unique users, I guess).

For example: if I had 10 users on my site last month and 3 of them each visited chat 10 times, while 7 of them never went to chat at all, I want to know that 3 people used the chat page (not that that the /chat page had 30 entries).

How can I get this out of Google Analytics?

Comment: Please advise on what you use for your chat. Companies can usually provide you with a report that you can extrapolate into a data base or a spreadsheet. Each person is identified with their unique IP address as well.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to mention - this is a question about Google Analytics! I just need to know how to find that info in GA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "Users" column to the "Content Drilldown" report.

1. Navigate to "Behavior" -> "Site Content" -> "Content Drilldown".
   [image: Google Analytics Content Drilldown Report with Edit]
2. Click to Edit that report
3. Add the "Users" metric.
   [image: Google Analytics Customize Content Drilldown Report]
4. Now that report of URLs on your site will have the "Users" column with the metric that you want.
5. If you want to find a specific URL from your site on that report, use the search functionality built into the report.  For example you might search for "/chat" if that is the URL path of chat on your site.

Comment: Important to note that you still need to manually calculate the percentage. For example I have a page `/store` and it shows `Users: 1433 (17.92%)` and on top it shows the total count `Users: 3398`. Now 1433/3398 = 0.42 (42%) and nowhere near 17.92. This is the number of users out of the total that visited the page. GA likes to make all rows add up to 100% which would only be accurate if each user only ever went to one page! To answer the question "What % of my users visited the store page" you have to manually divide it.

Comment: Would love to find a way to show this percentage automatically if there's a way.